# System ERror &H80072EFE in Excel on Windows 7

Tags: excel, rest

When I execute this macro in Excel on Windows 10 it runs fine, but it fails on windows 7 with this error:

System Error &H80072EFE The connection with the server was terminated abnormally

```
Sub CallURL()
    Dim url As String
    url = "https://www.energidataservice.dk/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=0e3dcd89-6bfd-4795-8f46-94df64fc0707&limit=5&sort=Minutes5%20desc"
    Set req = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    req.Open "GET", url, False
    req.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/json"
    req.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    req.Send ("")    
    Debug.Print req.Status
    If req.Status <> "200" Then
        MsgBox (req.ResponseText)
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

What is needed to make this work on Windows 7 ?

/Paul S

Comment: Is it related to https ?

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568934/calling-rest-api-from-vba-connection-with-the-server-was-terminated-abnormall/50057559#50057559

Answer (score 0):

Just change this
Set req = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
to
Set req = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")