# Calling Rest API from VBA - "Connection with the server was terminated abnormally"

Tags: c#, vba, excel, winhttprequest

I am trying to RESTfull API from Excel VBA. 
I already have a working version in C#:

```
//Request Auth Token
var client = new RestClient("https://api.xxx.com/exp/oauth2/v1/access_token_cors");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "response_type=token&grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=1234&client_secret=1234&scope=", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Need to port this code to VBA. I wrote:

```vb
Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
MyRequest.Open "POST", "https://api.xxx.com/exp/oauth2/v1/access_token_cors", False
MyRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
PostData = """application/x-www-form-urlencoded"", ""response_type=token&grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=1234&client_secret=1234&scope="""
MyRequest.send (PostData)
```

When I run the VBA version I get an error "Connection with the server was terminated abnormally" on .Send line

Since it works in C# it cannot be a firewall or server problems. What can I do to get it working? I have searched for similar questions but none there are applicable to my situation.

Comment: Could you use MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0?

Comment: Same result....

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do the following:

```
Set request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
request.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
request.Open "POST", URL, False 'Your missing the actual url
request.Option(4) 'Ignore SSL Errors.
request.Option(12) 'Allow redirect to SSL
request.send("response_type=token&grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=1234&client_secret=1234&scope=")
```

I assume the issue is, you don't have a defined URL.  More than likely the api could be SSL, so you should account for that, also why create a `PostData` when you can input the string.  You also have a lot of quotation marks, I assume you're doing that to correctly send them, I believe that is off.  The above should work for you.

Comment: Gregg, thank you for quick reply. Your solution did not work. First, I got an error that Open should be before setRequestHeader. After I moved it, I got the same error: Connection with the server was terminated abnormally

Comment: @anjulis If you download Fiddler, can you see what the request says?  Or post the data in Postman.  Does it return successfully or does the code error also?

Comment: I can run it in Postman or in C#. Only VBA has problem with the server.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have this issue on windows 7 or 8, it might be related to VBA sending data packets with SSL protocol which gets dropped by servers only accepting TLS.
In that case, You will need to apply a 2-step patch/update to fix this for windows 7,

**Step 1. Get Microsoft Update:**
Download relevant (32-bits or 64-bits of user's Windows version)
[Microsoft Security Protocol Update](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=kb3140245) and install if not already install.

**Step 2. Download Microsoft Easy Fix:**
 Download Microsoft “Easy Fix” from 
[Microsoft Support Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi), and execute to set TLS 1.1+ as default.

Source : [Update to enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 as default secure protocols in WinHTTP in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi)